# Writing java makefile for copy xml files to output directory

Tags: java, xml, makefile

In my Java application,I want to add a directory inside my package structure. This directory contains some XML files. Since these files cannot be compiled, I want to copy these files during war make process. How to write a `makefile` for this?

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question directly, but I think you're much better off investigating Ant or Maven for Java builds. Maven in particular will handle the above seamlessly

Comment: I cannot go for this,since it is an existing application

Comment: You're editing a makefile - can't you simply invoke Ant/Maven/whatever within your makefile ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing precisely what your directory structure looks like, I would simply say that you handle this in the same fashion as putting your class files into a `.war` file. A `.war` file is little more than a `.zip` file and doesn't really care what you put into it.

Going forwards, you should dump the `makefile` and investigate something more Java-centric. I would suggest Maven for its convention-directed approach. For example, the `war` goal of Maven will simply assume a directory structure and successfully build a `.war` file of suitable contents within those directories.